# How to convert a numpy.ma.MaskedArray to PyTorch masked tensors?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

Basically, the title conveys the question. Let's say we have

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
mx = np.ma.MaskedArray(np.random.rand(3, 3), mask=[[True, False, False], [True, False, True], [False, False, False]], fill_value=float('-inf'))
```

How do I convert `mx` to a PyTorch masked tensor?

Answer (score 0):

I found there is a [maskedtensor](https://pypi.org/project/maskedtensor/) package that does this job.

```py
import torch
from maskedtensor import masked_tensor
import numpy as np

def maskedarray2tensor(data: np.ma.MaskedArray) -> torch.Tensor:
    """Converts a numpy masked array to a masked tensor.
    """
    _data = torch.from_numpy(data)
    mask = torch.from_numpy(data.mask.astype(bool))
    return masked_tensor(_data, mask)
```